# Parallax JS needs to autoscroll to the next slide

Tags: parallax

I am trying to get my site http://s472215977.onlinehome.us/index.html  to scroll like www.prettybirdus.com.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check your JS console for errors.

Comment: [Something on your website doesn't work, but you can't just paste a link to it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a parallax banner for Playstation 4 recently - http://uk.playstation.com/ps4/features/ (Scroll down) which uses an open source framework I've been working on called Scrollr-Controllr - https://github.com/chrisgwgreen/Scrollr-Controllr

Its designed to provide highly efficient parallaxing and comes with a demo. Its a work in progress but feel free to ask questions if you're stuck.